# Finding the project title that has the maximum employees SQL Server & Listing employees with their total worked days

Tags: sql-server, database

Ive been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours.
I want to take out the max employees and this is what I got through the work. Yet I am getting a syntax error for some reason

```
    select title, count(A.employeeN)
from Project P, Allocation A
group by P.projectN
Having count(employeeN) = 
(select max(A.employeeN)
from (select count(A.employeeN) as employeeN_nbrofemployee
from Project P, Allocation A
where P.projectN = A.projectN
group by P.projectN));
```

The next one is Listing the employees (employeeN, name, totaldays) along with their total worked days. (Total days and employeeN are in the constructor)

Comment: You really need to get in the habit of using the ANSI-92 style join syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Looks like `A.employeeN` is the name, and `employeeN_nbrofemployee` is the alias for the count; so that's what you should be taking the max of.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way. You'll get far better help if you can give more information: What syntax error are you getting? Have you tried to run your subqueries by themselves, in order to isolate the source of the error? Edit your question and add any such information.

Comment: Hello @alexis thank you for your message. Mainly the syntax error is showing up in the end  "group by P.projectN));"

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, Sate 1 , Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Well, try the embedded queries (or variants) by themselves, as I suggested. And add the information to the question itself, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example here is how this query might look using current (well within the last 20 years) join syntax and some formatting.

```
select title
    , count(A.employeeN)
from Project P
join Allocation A ON P.projectN = A.projectN
group by P.projectN
Having count(employeeN) = 
(
    select max(x.employeeN_nbrofemployee)
    from 
    (
        select count(A.employeeN) as employeeN_nbrofemployee
        from Project P
        join Allocation A ON P.projectN = A.projectN
        group by P.projectN
    ) x --<<---- notice the alias here.
);
```

The question I have now is are you really trying to find rows where the count of employeeN values = the value of a specific employeeN? That seems like a logic problem there but I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the nested SELECT:

```
select title, count(A.employeeN)
from Project P, Allocation A
group by P.projectN
Having count(employeeN) = 
(select max   (B.employeeN_nnrofemployee)
from (select count(A.employeeN) as employeeN_nbrofemployee
from Project P, Allocation A
where P.projectN = A.projectN
group by P.projectN) B);
```

That should at least sort the syntax error...